# Evitar que se puedan abrir más de una ventana secundaria (Toplevel) al mismo tiempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy creando un bloc de notas simple con tkinter y en la ventana del bloc puse un botón que me abra otra ventana (llamemos a esta ventana "open") y en esa ventana poder escoger una nota ya guardada. Todo parecía marchar bien hasta que me di cuenta de algo:

Al presionar el botón por primera vez se abría la ventana *open*, todo bien hasta que se me dio por presionar otra ves el botón y se abrió otra vez la ventana *open* y lo presione otra ves y se abrió otra y así sucesivamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el botón se bloquee mientras tengo la ventana *open* abierta, y que al cerrarla se desbloquee el botón?

Este es el código necesario para reproducir el problema:

```
import tkinter as tk


win=tk.Tk()
win.resizable(0,0)
win.geometry("440x75+370+250")
win.config(bg="#0bad80") 
win.title("Open me")

def open():
    win_two=tk.Toplevel()
    win_two.geometry("300x75+370+300")
    win_two.title("Iam a window")
    win_two.config(bg="#0c5b7d")
    win_two_label=tk.Label(win_two,text="Hola...my friend ;)",font=('bold',16))
    win_two_label.config(bg="#0c5b7d",fg="white")
    win_two_label.place(x=10,y=20)


win_label=tk.Label(win,text="Other window-->")
win_label.config(bg="#0bad80",fg="white",font=('bold',16))
win_label.place(x=10,y=20)

win_button=tk.Button(win,text="Open",width=15,command=lambda:open())
win_button.config(bd=0,bg="#6da297",fg="white",font=('bold',13))
win_button.place(x=220,y=20)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sería mejor si cuelgas el texto del código en lugar de la imagen

Comment: aunque me costo un poco ordenarlo pero ya esta xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas dos cosas:

- Usar el método `config` del botón para establecer su atributo `state` en `disabled` o `normal`.
- Hacer uso de los [administradores de protocolo](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols)  para detectar e interceptar el click en el botón de cierre del gestor de ventanas de turno y poder habilitar el botón de nuevo.

En tu caso podría quedar algo así:

```
import tkinter as tk


win=tk.Tk()
win.resizable(0,0)
win.geometry("440x75+370+250")
win.config(bg="#0bad80") 
win.title("Open me")

def open_dialog():
    win_two=tk.Toplevel(win)
    win_two.geometry("300x75+370+300")
    win_two.title("Iam a window")
    win_two.config(bg="#0c5b7d")
    win_two_label=tk.Label(win_two,text="Hola...my friend ;)",font=('bold',16))
    win_two_label.config(bg="#0c5b7d",fg="white")
    win_two_label.place(x=10,y=20)

    win_button.config(state='disable')  # Deshabilitamos el botón

    def on_close():  
        '''
        Función que se llama cuando se pulsa el botón de cierre
        del gestor de ventanas 
        '''        
        win_two.destroy()  # Destruimos la ventana secundaria
        win_button.config(state='normal')  # habilitamos el botón


    win_two.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close) 


win_label=tk.Label(win,text="Other window-->")
win_label.config(bg="#0bad80",fg="white",font=('bold',16))
win_label.place(x=10,y=20)

win_button=tk.Button(win,text="Open",width=15,command=open_dialog)
win_button.config(bd=0,bg="#6da297",fg="white",font=('bold',13))
win_button.place(x=220,y=20)
win.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]